# ¿Cómo guardar el resultado de una consulta MySQL en una variable?

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de hacer un algoritmo para tener un contador el cual me va a servir para crear n número de contenedores, pero estoy atascado en el principio ya que no entiendo en que me estoy equivocando con respecto con php.

Tengo una línea de sql y estoy muy seguro de que está bien ya que cuando ejecuto la sentencia directamente en la base si me devuelve un resultado; esta parte del código que menciono es:

```
$sql = "SELECT count(ID_PRODUCTO) FROM producto WHERE DISPONIBILIDAD = 1 AND ID_CATEGORIA = 17";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$arr = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
echo $arr;
```

Como se ve en las líneas anteriores estoy tratando de imprimir en pantalla el resultado pero por alguna razón me dice que la función mysqli_fetch_array() está mal ya que esta recibiendo un booleano mientras que la sentencia devuelve un entero, intenté solo ver la variable $res pero solo me aparece la pantalla en blanco.

**Me pueden decir que estaría mal ya que también estoy consultando en la página de PHP sobre estos métodos?**

PS: estoy trabajando con phpmyadmin

error cuando trató de imprimir la variable -> Warning: Array to string conversion

Comment: Si entiendo bien tu pregunta, creo que esto puede ayudarte. Intenta cambiando $arr = mysqli_fetch_array($res);, por $arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res); o en su defecto si lo que quieres imprimir es un array debes usar print no echo.

Comment: Camilo te cuento que intenté con los cambios que me sugeriste pero me sigue saliendo la misma advertencia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según la documentación del método [mysqli_fetch_array](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) solo te falta acceder a la columna concreta dentro del array que te devuelve. Dado que solo tienes una columna y éstas se numeran empezando por cero

```
$sql = "SELECT count(ID_PRODUCTO) FROM producto WHERE DISPONIBILIDAD = 1 AND ID_CATEGORIA = 17";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$arr = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
echo $arr[0];
```

También según la documentación de [mysqli_query](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php)

> Retorna false en caso de error. Si una consulta del tipo **SELECT**, SHOW,
> DESCRIBE o EXPLAIN es exitosa, mysqli_query() retornará un objeto
> mysqli_result. Para otras consultas exitosas de mysqli_query()
> retornará true.

Es decir, para una consulta **SELECT** como la tuya, si te devuelve un booleano es porque se está produciendo algún error.

Comment: llegué a pensar que había un problema con la utilización de los métodos por lo que solo se obtiene un dato, pero muchas gracias no se me cruzó por la mente poner un índice

Comment: @SantiagoBarreiro Por nada, hombre :-)